# Template Installation Stuck : Joomla 3 + Rockettheme

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation

I have a new website setup installed on a host

Website Details :
Joomla Version : 3.4+
Template : Osmosis (Rockettheme) 
I am installing a template but I am getting an issue while installing it
I have a template bundle of around 1.2 MB so no issues of Max Upload limit

Steps :

 Select the file from file explorer  and upload it
And Then i get a completely blank screen .

When i log into FTP I see the template bundle and try it installing via directory
still same white blank page

I tried it using url by specifying the directory path
still same white blank page

I posted a ticket on the hosting but they mentioned something wrong about the files.I Tried them on localhost and they do work fine.

[image]

Here is the localhost screenshot of successful installation

[image]

I am currently unable to find the problem. What can be the possible error that i can fix 
 Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A Blank page is a PHP error page**, with disabled error reporting. You have to enable PHP error reporting to gather more information about what is going on.

In your hosting control panel, you can most probably enable PHP Error reporting. Additionally, your hosting support is able to check the Blank page or enable error reporting.

PD: It might be a memory limitation. Some hosters apply very low restrictions.

Comment: you were correct it was an update from the rockettheme for joomla 3.4. Which throwed an error after enabling error reporting on... good tip from to keep in mind . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Anibal suggests, please enable error reporting. That will probably give you (or us) an idea of what's going wrong.

There are several ways to enable error reporting:

1. **Joomla configuration:** Go to System -> Global Configuration -> Server tab -> Set error reporting to *Development*.
2. **php.ini:** You can set PHP error reporting on in **php.ini** file (in case you have access to this file). Set the following lines:

   ```
   error_reporting  =  E_ALL
   display_errors = On
   ```
3. **.htaccess:** You can also enable error reporting by editing your `.htaccess` file and adding these lines:

   ```
   php_flag display_errors on
   php_value error_reporting 6143
   ```

You can also try installing the template manually by extracting the .zip-file in `\templates\rt_osmosis`, and then use the Discover function in Joomla to install it (**Extensions -> Extension manager -> Discover**).

Make sure you have the Gantry Framework installed too, as the template requires it unless you're installing the Framework+Template bundle.

I highly recommend you try to find out *why* this happens by enabling error reporting, as you're likely to run into similar problems when installing other extensions.